# Deleting a row in mysql that I have entered through queries using a delete message button

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, jinja2

So I am creating a wall where people can send messages to other users. In my SQL I have two tables one for users and one for messages and the tables are labeled as such.

In my table for messages the column names are id, sender_id, message, created_at, updated_at, and recipient_id. The users table columns are as follows id, firstName, lastName, email, password(hashed), created_at, updated_at.

Sending messages is fine.  But when i tried creating a route to delete message in that person's wall i cant seem to get it to work.

the following is my code from my server.py file:

```
@app.route("/delete/<id>", methods=["POST"])
def delete(id):
    mysql=connectToMySQL('logindb')
    query = "DELETE FROM messages WHERE (id = request.form['user_id']) and (sender_id = session['sender_id]);"
    # DELETE FROM `logindb`.`messages` WHERE (`id` = '51') and (`sender_id` = '12');
    selecter = mysql.query_db(query)
    return redirect('/wall')
```

(the commented out code is my it looked in mySQL)

following is my create message route:

```
@app.route('/create_messages', methods=['POST'])
def create_messages():
    mysql=connectToMySQL('logindb')
    query = "INSERT INTO messages(message, created_at, updated_at, sender_id, recipient_id) values(%(messages)s, now(), now(), %(sender_id)s, %(recipient_id)s)"
    data = {
        'messages' : request.form['message'],
        'sender_id' : session['id'],
        'recipient_id' : request.form['user_id']
    }
    session['recipient_id'] = request.form['user_id']
    session['sender_id'] = session['id']
    print(session['recipient_id'],'THIS IS THE RECIPIENT ID !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
    print(session['sender_id'],'THIS IS THE SENDER ID !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
    inserter = mysql.query_db(query,data)
    return redirect('/wall')
```

On my wall.html file. I have two sections.  The section on the right is to create messages and the left is the messages that that specific user has.  I also have an error here that I want to fix if you can help me with, but this is a minor error.  So in the section where you can send messages somehow the logged in user can send messages to himself...  I didnt intend to do that, but i thought it might be cool kind of like reminders, but I do want to see if i can fix that as well.

Create message side:

```
<div class="right_messages">
        {%for messages in create%}
        <form action="/create_messages" method="post">
            {{messages['firstName']}}
            <textarea name="message"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value={{messages['id']}}>
            <input type="submit" value="send">
        </form>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
```

See and delete message side:

```
<div class="left_messages">
        <h3>{{count}} message(s) for you {{session['firstName']}}!</h3>
        <div class="messages">
        {%for messages in message%}
            <p>{{messages['firstName']}} said at {{messages['created_at']}} <br> {{messages['message']}}</p>
            <form method="post" action="/delete/{{message.id}}">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{message.id}}" name="id">
                <input type="submit" value="delete">
            </form>
        {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried using hidden inputs to do my transferring of the message id, but i couldn't implement it..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not a python/flask expert. Still looks like, the parameter passed-in is not the one used in the controller action. POST url parameter you send through `<form method="post" action="/delete/{{message.id}}">` to `@app.route("/delete/<id>", methods=["POST"])`  should hold the message.id in the 'id' variable. Should that not be used in the query instead of comparing to `request.form['user_id']` ?

Comment: thanks Raj, i figured out my problem.  My id was not getting through. I forgot the actually problem, but ya thanks for your help.